# Not able to execute typescript function

Tags: typescript2.0

I have a simple typescript function.

```
function disp_details(id:number,name:string,mail_id?:string) { 
   console.log("ID:", id); 
   console.log("Name",name); 

   if(mail_id!=undefined)  
   console.log("Email Id",mail_id); 
}
disp_details(123,"John");
disp_details(111,"mary","mary@xyz.com");
```

when I try to run the function in Vs code, I am getting an error.
C:\Apps\TypeScript-Test>node Script-4.ts

C:\Apps\TypeScript-Test\Script-4.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { function disp_details(id:number,name:string,mail_id?:string) {

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at vs coderap_node.js:612:3
```

I am using vscode , I am not able to resolve what is the issue.